# Why is there no such thing Array.TryGet in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

Everytime I have to access arrays via index, it bugs me that I have to check that I am not creating `IndexOutOfRange` Exceptions.

I get why arrays throw an exception instead of just returning `null`. That would be cool because I could use the `??` operator, but ok these are legacy types and I am fine with it.

But why did the BCL Team not implement `TryGet(int index, out T value)`
 like they did with, for example, `List<T>`?
From my understanding, they could have put this into the Linq Extensions as Array already implements IEnumerable

Comment: IEnumerable does not support indexes, so making such functionality work atop IEnumerable would be pretty painful.

Comment: Just make your own extension method, then we can all sleep better

Comment: "but ok these are legacy types and I am fine with it" - Except it is actually just as often that you want to store `null` as you want to avoid exceptions when you go past the boundaries. The array logic was written with a specific pattern in mind which is why it uses exceptions (specifically that you know the bounds). Anything else would introduce errors when a consumer of the class accidently did not check their bounds correctly.

Comment: OP is questioning the actual design decision made by the BCL team... telling him to make his own extension method doesn't help his question.

Comment: @DanLing It doesn't answer his question, but it may solve his problem of needing this method.  It's a valid comment, although not a valid answer.

Comment: Isn't [ElementAtOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) what you're looking for?

Comment: @DanLing: Correct. I am very much aware of the fact that I can write my own methods and was asking something completely different than what people are answering. This is like a kid asking "why can fished breathe under water whereas I cannot?" and something answering: "Thats not constructive, use diving equipment". Very disappointed with SO sometimes

Comment: @buddybubble: The reason this is not constructive it is very rare you will get a person who can answer these questions correctly - and by correctly I mean by someone who was involved in the design decisions in the first place. You could question why alot of built-in functions don't exist for things you deem common coding, but if Microsoft did everything for us, we wouldn't have our jobs... `this.FulfillCustomerRequirements();`

Comment: @nmclean: YES! Was not aware of that method. This is exactly what I had in mind (and it is even in the linq extensions as I assumed). Thank you for the only constructive answer to my question...

Comment: @musefan: this is a very simple answer you are giving.. There are a lot of very proficient .net / c# developers around like Eric Lippert or Gael Fraiteur. Besides that, nmclean DID answer my question so asking it was - at least for me- constructive. I can only assume that you were also not aware of `ElementAtOrDefault`

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn your thinking around - it is throwing `IndexOutOfRangeException` because you *should not be accessing those indexes in the first place*.

Instead, you should check the array length *before* you access the index:

```
string value = null;
if (i < array.Length) value = array[i];
```

or

```
for (int i=0; i<array.Length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

`IndexOutOfRangeException` is classed as a [boneheaded exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) - if it is being thrown, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I think that's the OP's exact complaint: that they are forced to perform this specific check at all.

Comment: @brad: you are right. Of course its easy to do, but it is tedious and mundane so I was wondering why ms did not already simplify it

Comment: Programming is "tedious and mundane". Programming languages can't be all things to all people.

Comment: @buddybubble: Point is, there's no `TryGet` partly because you shouldn't really ever be at the point where this happens.  If your index is outside the bounds of your array, you've run off the rails somewhere...and if you're *try*ing to get it just in case it's invalid, you're basically guessing about your code's state.  And that hardly ever turns out well.

Comment: @cHao: I generally agree with you. Right now however, I work under an interface that expects several arrays as input. I have to use the same index and perform some calculations on each of the arrays. They should match each other in length, but you never know.. I also agree with you that this is a very dirty thing to do, but some things you just have to do

Comment: @spender "Programming is tedious and mundane" - huh? The tedious and the mundane is the _problem_ for which programming is the _solution_. It's our job to eliminate pointless complexity, not to blithely accept it.

Comment: @nmclean: my point was really that the language and runtime offer plenty of ways to ensure that you don't overshoot your arrays. Just because OP has devised an alternative way doesn't mean it should be incorporated. After all, we don't want another PHP, do we?

Comment: +1 for "boneheaded". The idioms are so common that you really shouldn't ever get this wrong.

Comment: @spender But it's not an "alterative" to this way, it's simply an easier interface to it. The code @thecoop posted here is _exactly_ what `Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault` does -- it checks if the enumerable implements `IList` and does `if (index < list.Count) return list[index];` If you're manually writing the same check often, looking for a more straightforward approach is a perfectly reasonable response. It's certainly better than accepting tediousness as the norm and continuing to write repetitive code without even considering whether it might be unnecessary.